# Get data from database and put it in array

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
$product_array = array(
   "106" => array(
      'product_id'=>'106', 
      'product_catgegory'=>'Accessories', 
      'product_name'=>'Headphone with mic',
      'product_desc'=>'', 
      'product_price'=>'148.85', 
      'product_img'=>'products/product8.jpg'
   )
);
```

I always get data from database like this :

```
$query = "select * from meal where cat='$id'";
$encode = mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8");
$func = mysqli_query($con , $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($func)) {
   $ida = $row['id'];
   $name = $row['name'];
   $img = $row['img'];
   $id = $row['id'];
   $price = $row['price'];
   $desc = $row['desc'];
}
```

My problem is I want to write data received from the database in array, for
example:

```
$product_array = array(
   "106" =>array(
      'product_id'=>'$id', 
      'product_catgegory'=>'$cat', 
      'product_name'=>'$name',
      'product_desc'=>'', 
      'product_price'=>'$price', 
      'product_img'=>'$img'
   )
);
```

Comment: What is the difference between `$ida` and `$id`? They refer to the same result column

Comment: `$product_array[] = $row`?

Comment: Did any of these help you?

Answer (score 1):

Two good ways.  Both use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`:

Select the columns you want (don't use `*`) and combine the row with an array of keys:

```
$query = "SELECT id, cat, name, desc, price, img FROM meal WHERE cat='$id'";
$keys = array('product_id', 'product_catgegory', 'product_name','product_desc', 'product_price', 'product_img');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($func)) {    
    $product_array[$row['id']] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
```

Or just alias the column names using `AS`:

```
$query = "SELECT id AS product_id, cat AS product_catgegory, name AS product_name, desc AS product_desc, price AS product_price, img AS product_img FROM meal WHERE cat='$id'";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($func)) {    
    $product_array[$row['product_id']] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Not work   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: What?  There is no `foreach` in my code or your code.  I see where this is going... :-(

Answer (score 0):

**CAUSE**

You should not use single quotes because variables like `'$id'` don't get interpreted by PHP.

**SOLUTION**

See below the updated code. It's unclear what should be used for `product_catgegory` so I left it blank.

```
$query = "select * from meal where cat='$id'";
$encode = mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES utf8");
$func = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($func)) {
   $product_array[$row['id']] = array(
      'product_id'        => $row['id'], 
      'product_catgegory' => '', 
      'product_name'      => $row['name'],
      'product_desc'      => $row['desc'], 
      'product_price'     => $row['price'], 
      'product_img'       => $row['img']
   )
}
```

**NOTES**

Make sure you do something like `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $id);` before running `mysqli_query()` otherwise, you're open to SQL injection attack.